# spliting column into 2 and replace character by number - R

Tags: r, extract, stringr, strsplit

I have obtained results in the following format:

```
     Parameter  Wert
...
99      se.m  0.1000
100     se.m  0.1000
101    se.st  0.5000
102    se.st  0.500
...
```

I want to split the column `Parameter` into two columns: `Parameter` and `Insentität`. The split should be done where the dot `.` is.  Then in the resulting column `Intensität`, I want to replace all `m` by the value of `2` and replace all `st` by the value of `3`. The result should look like this:

```
Parameter Intensität Wert
...
99  se        2  0.4000
100 se        2  0.0396
101 se        3  0.2702
102 se        3  1.1566
...
```

I have managed to obtain this format, however i am sure there is a more elegant way to do.

The way i have obtained the results is clumsy. I originally had 2 columns in the output: `se.m` and `se.st`. I have manually changed the column names:

```
colnames(results) <- c("2", "3")
```

and then combined the two columns into 1 column. Then i added a column containing the characters `se` in every row.

```
results <- melt(results)
cbind( Parameter ="se", results)
```

I know there is another alretnatives. For example by using `extract` from `tidyr`, but i cannot get the expression syntax right. Also `stringr` package, I could use str_`match` function or maybe also `strsplit`. All these look great but i seem to be unable to apply them to my problem. I am stuck here. There are similiar question, but I couldnt find a solution that works for me.

PS: I appriciate any input -  comments, critique, tips. I am a learner and any piece of advice is of a great value to me.

Comment: check [Rpubs](https://rpubs.com/bradleyboehmke/data_wrangling)  for Data Processing with dplyr & tidyr. I found it after asking this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `separate`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
separate(df1, Parameter, into = c("Parameter", "Intensitat")) %>%
                mutate(Intensitat = recode(Intensitat, m = 2, st = 3))

#  Parameter Intensitat Wert
#1        se          2  0.1
#2        se          2  0.1
#3        se          3  0.5
#4        se          3  0.5
```

---

Or we can separate using `read.table` by specifying the `sep`, do a `transform`ation and `cbind` with the "Wert" column

```
cbind(transform(read.table(text= as.character(df1$Parameter), 
    col.names = c("Parameter", "Intensitat"), sep="."), 
      Intensitat = ifelse(Intensitat=="m", 2, 3)), df1["Wert"])
#    Parameter Intensitat Wert
#99         se          2  0.1
#100        se          2  0.1
#101        se          3  0.5
#102        se          3  0.5
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun, this is exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: I just read about the pipe operator `%>%` on [Rpubs](https://rpubs.com/bradleyboehmke/data_wrangling) which lead me to other functions like `separete`. Just though I would drop it here, might be of use for other students with similiar problem

Comment: @Danka Yes, there are lots of useful functions in the tidyverse list of packages